# ZFS: Unable to expand pool after increasing disk size in vmware

Tags: resize, expand, zfs

I have a Centos7 VM with ZFS on linux installed.
The VM has a disk /dev/sdb, that I've added to a pool named 'backup', and in this pool created a dataset.
Now, I wanted to increase the size of the disk in VMware, and then expand the size of the pool, but I'm not getting this to work.

- I've tried 'zpool online -e backup sdb', but nothing changes.
- I've tried running 'partprobe /dev/sdb' before and after the live above, but nothing changes.
- I've tried rebooting + the above, nothing changes.
- I've tried "parted /dev/sdb",resizing the partition (it suggests the actual new size of the volume), and then all of the above. But nothing changes
- I've tried 'zpool export backup' + 'zpool import backup' in various combinations with all of the above. No luck

And also: 'lsblk' and 'df -h' reports the old/wrong size of /dev/sdb, even if parted seems to understand that it has been increased.
PS: autoexpand=on

What to do?

Comment: When you create a pool from a set of devices on Linux, I’ve seen ZFS create a bogus little partition after the main one that you have to remove to allow expansion to work. Do you see one of those?

Comment: Yes, there is a "bogus little partition" there. I'm reading that it is there for Solaris compatibility, and should not be necessary for when using Linux. After deleting this partition, and running partprobe I was able to expand the zpool with "zpool online -e <poolname> /dev/sdb".
I've not found any mentions about this until now. Am I bad at googling, or is this very poorly documented?

Comment: I felt like it was a bug rather than a documentation problem -- if ZFS creates the partition for Solaris compatibility, why doesn't it move it automatically when the vdev could be resized otherwise? That said, I agree it is also poorly documented what the current state is.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue today and had to try a lot before finding the solution.

When I tried the known solutions (using zpool) of setting autoexpand as on and also restarting the partprobe, system would not auto expand (even after a restart).

Finally, I could solve it using **parted** instead of getting into zpool at all.

We need to be careful here since wrong partition selections can cause data loss.

What worked for me in your situation

Step 1: Find which pool you are trying to expand.  In my case, it is 5 as seen below (unallocated space is after this pool).  Use **parted -l**

```
parted -l
```

Output

```
Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 69.8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  540MB   538MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 3      540MB   2009MB  1469MB                                     swap
 4      2009MB  3592MB  1583MB  zfs
 5      3592MB  32.2GB  28.6GB  zfs
```

Step 2: Instructing explictly to expany pool number 5 to 100% available.  Note that '5' is not static.  You need to use the pool id you wish to expand.  Double-check this. Use **parted /dev/XXX resizepart YY 100%**

```
parted /dev/sda resizepart 5 100%
```

After this, I was able to use the entire space in VM.

For reference:

LSBSK Before

```
sda                8:0    0    65G  0 disk  
├─sda1             8:1    0     1M  0 part  
├─sda2             8:2    0   513M  0 part  /boot/grub
│                                           /boot/efi
├─sda3             8:3    0   1.4G  0 part  
│ └─cryptoswap   253:1    0   1.4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda4             8:4    0   1.5G  0 part  
└─sda5             8:5    0  29.5G  0 part
```

LSBSK After

```
sda                8:0    0    65G  0 disk  
├─sda1             8:1    0     1M  0 part  
├─sda2             8:2    0   513M  0 part  /boot/grub
│                                           /boot/efi
├─sda3             8:3    0   1.4G  0 part  
│ └─cryptoswap   253:1    0   1.4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda4             8:4    0   1.5G  0 part  
└─sda5             8:5    0  61.7G  0 part
```